# How to find the smallest element in non STL graph?

Tags: c++, function

I have a non stl graph and this is one of my functions. I'm trying to go trough all of the elements and find the smallest. So far this get's the gob done to get through them.

```
void list_node(link *gr[n])
    {
        cout << "\n Graph: " << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        {
            if (gr[i]) 
            {
                cout << gr[i]->key << "  ";
            }
        }
}
```

I can't understand what I'm doing wrong but it doesn't seem to work. Keeps giving me error Error    2   error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'link *' How do I optimise it to work properly? Lines that give me errors are:

```
p=gr[i]->key;  
temp_num=p->key;
if(temp_num<final_num)
final_num=temp_num;
```

All of them are from here:

```
const int n = 10;

struct link
{
    int key;
    link *next;
}   *gr[n];




int dfs(link *gr[n])  
{   link *p=NULL;
    link *temp_num=NULL;
    int final_num=5;
    cout << "\n Graph: " << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        {
            if (gr[i])  //ako ima elementi
            {   

                p=gr[i]->key;

                if(p>gr[i]->next)
                {   
                    p=gr[i]->next;
                    temp_num=p;
                }
                else
                    temp_num=p->key;
                if(temp_num<final_num)
                {
                    final_num=temp_num;
                }

            }

        } 
    return final_num;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here `if(p>gr[i]->next)`? How/why do you want to compare an `int` and a `link*`?

Comment: Which line of code gives the error exactly?

Comment: lines are: p=gr[i]->key;        temp_num=p->key;     if(temp_num<final_num)    final_num=temp_num;

Comment: Thanks, but please add that information to the question itself.

Comment: I'm trying to compare them in order to find the smallest

Answer (score 0):

Your `list_node` function is very close to what you need. All you need is an extra variable that keeps track of the maximum value seen.

```
int maximum_node(link *gr[n])
{
    int max = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();  // initialize max
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)  
    {
        if (gr[i]) 
        {
            max = std::max(gr[i]->key, max);    // update max
         }
    }
    return max;   
}
```